# How to Delete/Remove Graphs(charts), Pictures(Images) from excel file loaded into PHPExcel?

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel class and i am loading template speadsheets and then modifying data and so forth.

Depending on what i pass my script dynamically, certain images in the template should be remove  and certain graphs(charts) should be removed.

I have used the `getChartCollection()` and the `getDrawingCollection()` to get everything but i havent figured out a way to modify the collections so that i can remove charts, and/or images from a 
loaded template.

Thanks for any help.
Jason K.

UPDATE - Thanks to info from Mark Baker below.
I wrote the following code that needs to be added to worksheet class until 1.7.9 is released.
My code is below.

```
/**
 * Remove drawing from collection
 *
 * @return PHPExcel_Worksheet_BaseDrawing[]
 */
public function removeImageByIDs($IDs)
{
    if(!is_array($IDs)) $IDs = array($IDs);
    $drawing_collection = $this->_drawingCollection;
    $drawing_collection_copy = $drawing_collection->getArrayCopy();
    foreach($IDs as $ID){
        unset($drawing_collection_copy[$ID]);
    }
    $drawing_collection_copy = array_values($drawing_collection_copy);
    $drawing_collection->exchangeArray($drawing_collection_copy);
    $this->_drawingCollection = $drawing_collection;
    unset($drawing_collection_copy);
    unset($drawing_collection);
    return $this->_drawingCollection;       
}

 /**
 * Remove chart from collection
 *
 * @return PHPExcel_Worksheet_BaseDrawing[]
 */
public function removeChartByIDs($IDs)
{
    if(!is_array($IDs)) $IDs = array($IDs);
    $chart_collection = $this->_chartCollection;
    $chart_collection_copy = $chart_collection->getArrayCopy();
    foreach($IDs as $ID){
        unset($chart_collection_copy[$ID]);
    }
    $chart_collection_copy = array_values($chart_collection_copy);
    $chart_collection->exchangeArray($chart_collection_copy);
    $this->_chartCollection = $chart_collection;
    unset($chart_collection_copy);
    unset($chart_collection);
    return $this->_chartCollection;
}
```

Enjoy. Jason K.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Believe it or not, this is the first time that anybody has ever asked about removing charts or images from a spreadsheet. PHPExcel doesn't actually have any methods for this, but they'd be easy enough for you to add yourself. The methods to add entries in these collections are in the PHPExcel_Worksheet class; and as the collection is simply an array, then it's simply a case of using unset(), array_splice() or similar to remove the entries you don't want.

Comment: Perfect and thanks for the quick answer.  That is wierd nobody has asked for it. Would it be possible to add this into the next release so that i/others dont have to worry about readding that functionality everytime we update this great class.

Comment: It's easy enough to do, so I shall add it for the 1.7.9 release: removeChartByID and removeImageByID using the sequence ID number as the argument

Comment: Mark Baker that sounds perfect and thanks for the help. The code above is my fix until v1.7.9 is released.  It takes in array of indexes as well as a single index.  Thanks again.